# css gap in between each line of a paragraph

Tags: css

**HTML**

```
<p>First line<br>leads to second<br>and then a third</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    color: #ffd11f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
    display: inline;
}
```

With the above I have tried to have a small gap in between each line but I'm unable to get this done. The `<p>` format needs to be in that style and I was hoping with css I would be able to have a padded background colour on each line like a label and then a small gap in between each line

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmxqY/)

Comment: You want to do that without a break tag?

Comment: Have you tried to change `line-height`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien need the break to put the text to new line

Comment: Try 'line-height' property.

Comment: Those of you suggesting `line-height` should read the question again.

Comment: @Donald You may be interested in this article: http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/NmxqY/1/

Comment: @Donald Am not getting you ..

Comment: The description “a padded background colour on each line like a label and then a small gap in between each line” is difficult to understand. Can you explain in directly observable terms and/or show an image of the desired appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about adding a `<span>` for each line? (Hoping that is possible to change the html). You can see my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/c5cPB/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
    p {line-height:200%}

You can change the percentage to whatever you prefer.

Comment: Read the question again. Not what the author needs.

Comment: It is not clear at first what he wanted, which is why two other people also suggested the line-height.

Comment: You should have flagged instead of answered then.